# Make MIFARE Classic 1K read only through an Android app

Tags: android, nfc, access-control, rfid, mifare

I would like to make MIFARE Classic 1k cards read only after writing some initial data to them. I guess I need to change keys A and B to something custom after writing data to the new card. But how do I do that? These keys are located in the same block as the access bits, so I can't use MifareClassic method for writing a complete block:

```
public void writeBlock(int blockIndex, byte[] data) throws IOException
```

because it will also rewrite the access bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you need to use the method `MifareClassic.writeBlock()`. Since MIFARE Classic only supports writing complete blocks, you have to update the whole sector trailer block.

As MIFARE Classic does not have a free read mode (i.e. read without prior authentication) you need to set both, a read key (you would typically use key A for that) and the access bits (that cofigure key A as read-only key).

You can find further information about possible access condition values and the block format here:

- [Locking mechanism of Mifare Classic 1K](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27885861/2425802)
- [MIFARE Classic: How to find to good Access Byte value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23753092/2425802)
- [Set own authentication keys MiFare Classic with APDU C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23616263/2425802)